# May one propose with an engagement ring?

Tags: halacha, sources-mekorot, marriage, shidduchim-dating, jewelry

Are there any Halachic issues with giving a girl a ring while asking her to marry him? Are there any sources that discuss the sha'alah of safek Kiddushin, etc?

Comment: Are there witnesses?

Comment: either way - where can I find mekorot for this?

Comment: I heard somewhere that it's safest to have in mind that it's not for Kiddushin, just in case. Don't remember where I heard this, sorry.

Comment: From my notes: One should not offer a ring and say “will you marry me” whiled dating as a joke, because the women might need a get mi’safek. One should also be careful when getting engaged not to say “will you marry me” and hand over a ring in front of witnesses. 

Rema – We look at the action. If it looks like a marriage, it is.

Comment: As I found while asking [this](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/38602/is-the-maharshals-list-of-differences-between-talmud-bavli-and-talmud-yerushalm) question, apparently it's a dispute between the Bavli and the Yerushalmi (look in the end, item כ"ד).

Comment: @Shmuel "Having in mind" works for being mekayem mitzvos because the negative kavana can negate the mitzva effect, but regarding bein adam lechavero we say דברים שבל אינם דברים, roughly thoughts of the heart have no bearing on the legal status of the action

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1936/5323

Comment: This is discussed in Techumin 39, where the authors discourage giving a ring in front of any witnesses.

Answer (score 7):

The Lubavitcher Rebbe [specifically discouraged](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14942&st=&pgnum=521&hilite=) giving a ring at any time during the engagement. (The practice in Chabad is to give the diamond ring<sup>*</sup> in the Cheder HaYichud after the Chuppa, and even other gifts are not given directly, or at least not with witnesses).

This is apparently explained at length in a Sicha of Nasso 5741, but I couldn't find it in [the online transcript](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=4628&st=&pgnum=589&hilite=).

<sup>*As far as I know, this idea was an invention of De Beers</sup>

Comment: Eliezer gave gifts to Rivka?

Comment: @c.benyosef, as far as I know that is called kiddusin in some places.

Comment: The reason you can't find it is because the citation is to Ki Tisa 5741 not Nasso

Comment: Here is a link to the citation: http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=4627&st=&pgnum=534