# Is the Maharshal's list of differences between Talmud Bavli and Talmud Yerushalmi complete?

Tags: halacha, product-recommendation, talmud-bavli, talmud-yerushalmi

I found [here](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/3058) a book written by the Maharshal citing where pasukim are found in the Yerushalmi. In the end of this book, he cites a number of differences in halacha between the Bavli and the Yerushalmi. Is this complete? And if not, where can I find a complete list?

Comment: For what it's worth, the book that you have cited is not by the Maharshal: it's by R' Menachem Mendel Hochstein. Only the final three pages are by the Maharshal, comprising a list of differences between Babylonia and the land of Israel in both custom and law. It appears to be complete, although R' Hochstein doesn't cite its source and I've not yet found it in any of the Maharshal's writings.

Comment: The reason I'm wondering about its completeness is that there are a number of conclusions I've found in the Talmud Yerushalmi that are not listed where I've linked.

Comment: @ShimonbM This collection from Maharshal was appended to his Yam Shel Shlomo ([BK, end](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=40932&st=&pgnum=264)).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not necessarily complete; the matter is more complicated than it may seem because neither Talmud is always so clear as to how it views the final halakha, and complicated further by the fact that we don't have such a reliable text of the Yerushalmi in many instances. Most commentaries 'on the daf' of the Yerushalmi tend to minimize the differences between them (meaning, explain the Yerushalmi according to the Bavli) but their readings often seem forced.

The best book that's closest to a complete list (because he mentions everywhere that there *might* be a disagreement) is **Amrei Bemaarava**, by Achikam Keshset. The book is available online (I assume legally), at http://daf-yomi.com/BookFiles.aspx?type=1&id=36&page=17&male=0

Comment: Funnily enough, I ordered that book earlier today... (through a 3rd party so I'm not sure of the status of the online version).