# Chapters of Tanach present in Talmud Yerushalmi

Tags: talmud-gemara, number, tanach, talmud-yerushalmi, statistics

[Chapters of Tanach present in Talmud Bavli](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/92084/9682) asks:

> I heard there is a style of Talmud study somewhere, where as a verse presents itself in the Talmud, the student would learn the entire chapter from תנ״ך.
>
> With that, were one to complete the entire Talmud Bavli, would he also have completed the entire תנ״ך?

[As I answered there](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/99867/9682), one covers about 95% of Tanach with this method.

What if one does this with Talmud Yerushalmi? Would one end up completing more of Tanach with this method? Which perakim are left out, if any? Does applying this method to Yerushalmi cover the perakim not covered by Bavli?

Comment: Gains zeraim, loses kodoshim. Also I think just generally a shorter text. This seems significantly more difficult than the other question

Comment: @Dr.Shmuel Quality, not quantity. :)

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/38602/is-the-maharshals-list-of-differences-between-talmud-bavli-and-talmud-yerushalm?r=SearchResults

Comment: http://hebrewbooks.org/24549

Comment: @Dr.Shmuel If you want to read through that and get back to me, be my guest. :)

Comment: @DonielF "hm maybe I can just OCR it and then" ... [glances at one page] -- um, no!

Answer (score 5):

Major caveat: mechon-mamre's edition of Yerushalmi on Nezikin and on doesn't include the parentheses to indicate a biblical citation. So my scripts didn't "see" any citations there.

(Fun fact: as it appears in mechon mamre, both Bavli and Yerushalmi occasionally reference a chapter that doesn't exist (e.g. Shemos 46); most likely a typo on the chapter number.)

As I count it, there are 929 chapters in Tanach. 900 (97%) of those are cited by at least one Talmud, and 29 not cited at all. 886 (95%) of those appear in the Bavli; the Yerushalmi only adds 14 more (2%).

The Yerushalmi cites 718 chapters, so 77%. (Though when you consider that the Yerushalmi total text is about half that of the Bavli, it's citing pretty thoroughly -- especially with Nezikin tied behind its back.)

Once you're going through all this work, you might as well rank each perek by how often it appears in each Talmud -- for simplicity's sake, let's ignore ties; if two perakim have the same number of citations, the textually-first one gets the better rank. Anything with a rank of '?' means it's not cited; you can filter on those to focus more on the uncited chapters.

```
Perek_order Perek   Bavli_rank  Yerushalmi_rank
1    בראשית א   52  30
2    בראשית ב   66  37
3    בראשית ג   205 423
4    בראשית ד   208 319
5    בראשית ה   375 265
6    בראשית ו   93  145
7    בראשית ז   115 380
8    בראשית ח   185 290
9    בראשית ט   87  509
10   בראשית י   524 473
11   בראשית יא  281 295
12   בראשית יב  229 392
13   בראשית יג  210 526
14   בראשית יד  231 706
15   בראשית טו  197 694
16   בראשית טז  573 281
17   בראשית יז  123 67
18   בראשית יח  56  129
19   בראשית יט  167 152
20   בראשית כ   188 203
21   בראשית כא  162 487
22   בראשית כב  142 385
23   בראשית כג  310 525
24   בראשית כד  111 92
25   בראשית כה  89  723
26   בראשית כו  450 424
27   בראשית כז  169 387
28   בראשית כח  214 297
29   בראשית כט  435 676
30   בראשית ל   269 313
31   בראשית לא  217 143
32   בראשית לב  165 342
33   בראשית לג  174 576
34   בראשית לד  462 95
35   בראשית לה  331 402
36   בראשית לו  461 550
37   בראשית לז  156 439
38   בראשית לח  125 98
39   בראשית לט  250 438
40   בראשית מ   778 196
41   בראשית מא  338 236
42   בראשית מב  394 126
43   בראשית מג  346 668
44   בראשית מד  558 534
45   בראשית מה  528 352
46   בראשית מו  500 519
47   בראשית מז  317 139
48   בראשית מח  135 131
49   בראשית מט  71  119
50   בראשית נ   184 320
51   שמות א     120 ?
52   שמות ב     190 178
53   שמות ג     168 457
54   שמות ד     107 96
55   שמות ה     534 667
56   שמות ו     293 356
57   שמות ז     516 ?
58   שמות ח     705 ?
59   שמות ט     665 722
60   שמות י     750 539
61   שמות יא    540 470
62   שמות יב    4   1
63   שמות יג    49  44
64   שמות יד    294 184
65   שמות טו    63  124
66   שמות טז    80  65
67   שמות יז    227 364
68   שמות יח    131 177
69   שמות יט    84  91
70   שמות כ     37  16
71   שמות כא    2   17
72   שמות כב    6   22
73   שמות כג    38  14
74   שמות כד    85  94
75   שמות כה    69  36
76   שמות כו    133 142
77   שמות כז    114 193
78   שמות כח    74  49
79   שמות כט    61  63
80   שמות ל     60  29
81   שמות לא    113 168
82   שמות לב    90  53
83   שמות לג    118 191
84   שמות לד    48  54
85   שמות לה    206 81
86   שמות לו    459 459
87   שמות לז    ?   ?
88   שמות לח    419 641
89   שמות לט    623 277
90   שמות מ     173 146
91   ויקרא א    18  57
92   ויקרא ב    42  55
93   ויקרא ג    64  253
94   ויקרא ד    11  46
95   ויקרא ה    10  73
96   ויקרא ו    9   19
97   ויקרא ז    8   24
98   ויקרא ח    260 102
99   ויקרא ט    277 140
100  ויקרא י    57  116
101  ויקרא יא   14  42
102  ויקרא יב   54  48
103  ויקרא יג   43  72
104  ויקרא יד   25  61
105  ויקרא טו   27  340
106  ויקרא טז   17  4
107  ויקרא יז   31  101
108  ויקרא יח   33  28
109  ויקרא יט   7   2
110  ויקרא כ    51  86
111  ויקרא כא   23  25
112  ויקרא כב   5   12
113  ויקרא כג   12  3
114  ויקרא כד   40  45
115  ויקרא כה   1   13
116  ויקרא כו   82  336
117  ויקרא כז   3   33
118  במדבר א    512 518
119  במדבר ב    539 466
120  במדבר ג    257 595
121  במדבר ד    253 254
122  במדבר ה    13  9
123  במדבר ו    21  5
124  במדבר ז    275 605
125  במדבר ח    240 130
126  במדבר ט    59  87
127  במדבר י    92  62
128  במדבר יא   67  205
129  במדבר יב   119 114
130  במדבר יג   143 206
131  במדבר יד   116 147
132  במדבר טו   28  38
133  במדבר טז   102 662
134  במדבר יז   463 578
135  במדבר יח   20  18
136  במדבר יט   34  82
137  במדבר כ    255 477
138  במדבר כא   140 60
139  במדבר כב   382 593
140  במדבר כג   128 383
141  במדבר כד   146 141
142  במדבר כה   144 ?
143  במדבר כו   189 608
144  במדבר כז   73  586
145  במדבר כח   53  52
146  במדבר כט   77  84
147  במדבר ל    47  43
148  במדבר לא   76  115
149  במדבר לב   400 200
150  במדבר לג   329 185
151  במדבר לד   642 183
152  במדבר לה   35  85
153  במדבר לו   212 272
154  דברים א    81  250
155  דברים ב    177 346
156  דברים ג    268 454
157  דברים ד    44  27
158  דברים ה    106 89
159  דברים ו    50  39
160  דברים ז    72  41
161  דברים ח    101 103
162  דברים ט    284 486
163  דברים י    110 64
164  דברים יא   55  31
165  דברים יב   16  21
166  דברים יג   46  104
167  דברים יד   29  15
168  דברים טו   32  34
169  דברים טז   30  10
170  דברים יז   36  50
171  דברים יח   62  190
172  דברים יט   39  247
173  דברים כ    100 47
174  דברים כא   26  26
175  דברים כב   15  8
176  דברים כג   22  20
177  דברים כד   19  6
178  דברים כה   24  7
179  דברים כו   58  11
180  דברים כז   75  207
181  דברים כח   45  40
182  דברים כט   211 202
183  דברים ל    228 100
184  דברים לא   103 88
185  דברים לב   65  35
186  דברים לג   41  75
187  דברים לד   200 214
188  יהושוע א   368 279
189  יהושוע ב   444 299
190  יהושוע ג   505 725
191  יהושוע ד   352 724
192  יהושוע ה   187 631
193  יהושוע ו   506 132
194  יהושוע ז   153 316
195  יהושוע ח   413 273
196  יהושוע ט   754 528
197  יהושוע י   447 575
198  יהושוע יא  755 614
199  יהושוע יב  ?   659
200  יהושוע יג  770 ?
201  יהושוע יד  640 597
202  יהושוע טו  491 ?
203  יהושוע טז  886 665
204  יהושוע יז  641 ?
205  יהושוע יח  706 455
206  יהושוע יט  578 376
207  יהושוע כ   771 ?
208  יהושוע כא  765 699
209  יהושוע כב  885 551
210  יהושוע כג  ?   615
211  יהושוע כד  418 425
212  שופטים א   279 451
213  שופטים ב   841 ?
214  שופטים ג   756 702
215  שופטים ד   617 ?
216  שופטים ה   98  357
217  שופטים ו   370 315
218  שופטים ז   773 399
219  שופטים ח   718 348
220  שופטים ט   722 637
221  שופטים י   804 ?
222  שופטים יא  745 573
223  שופטים יב  868 ?
224  שופטים יג  341 700
225  שופטים יד  330 195
226  שופטים טו  599 ?
227  שופטים טז  159 689
228  שופטים יז  536 ?
229  שופטים יח  764 311
230  שופטים יט  862 ?
231  שופטים כ   685 660
232  שופטים כא  630 ?
233  שמואל א א  203 70
234  שמואל א ב  79  58
235  שמואל א ג  464 321
236  שמואל א ד  697 366
237  שמואל א ה  835 590
238  שמואל א ו  478 388
239  שמואל א ז  595 386
240  שמואל א ח  576 716
241  שמואל א ט  664 174
242  שמואל א י  741 ?
243  שמואל א יא     801 ?
244  שמואל א יב     364 489
245  שמואל א יג     845 580
246  שמואל א יד     295 186
247  שמואל א טו     410 ?
248  שמואל א טז     274 266
249  שמואל א יז     132 326
250  שמואל א יח     727 ?
251  שמואל א יט     883 ?
252  שמואל א כ  612 648
253  שמואל א כא     425 349
254  שמואל א כב     657 566
255  שמואל א כג     611 327
256  שמואל א כד     605 322
257  שמואל א כה     181 458
258  שמואל א כו     782 720
259  שמואל א כז     ?   ?
260  שמואל א כח     365 671
261  שמואל א כט     ?   ?
262  שמואל א ל  588 362
263  שמואל א לא     815 727
264  שמואל ב א  581 149
265  שמואל ב ב  760 719
266  שמואל ב ג  213 393
267  שמואל ב ד  ?   ?
268  שמואל ב ה  619 624
269  שמואל ב ו  376 269
270  שמואל ב ז  306 122
271  שמואל ב ח  639 ?
272  שמואל ב ט  784 681
273  שמואל ב י  776 ?
274  שמואל ב יא     553 530
275  שמואל ב יב     198 680
276  שמואל ב יג     356 445
277  שמואל ב יד     487 ?
278  שמואל ב טו     271 226
279  שמואל ב טז     589 ?
280  שמואל ב יז     319 520
281  שמואל ב יח     349 482
282  שמואל ב יט     555 220
283  שמואל ב כ  708 ?
284  שמואל ב כא     178 151
285  שמואל ב כב     324 ?
286  שמואל ב כג     224 639
287  שמואל ב כד     407 ?
288  מלכים א א  112 181
289  מלכים א ב  298 623
290  מלכים א ג  695 693
291  מלכים א ד  386 ?
292  מלכים א ה  565 416
293  מלכים א ו  137 93
294  מלכים א ז  348 197
295  מלכים א ח  83  78
296  מלכים א ט  551 462
297  מלכים א י  679 ?
298  מלכים א יא     209 485
299  מלכים א יב     429 367
300  מלכים א יג     634 282
301  מלכים א יד     247 ?
302  מלכים א טו     554 ?
303  מלכים א טז     769 517
304  מלכים א יז     350 171
305  מלכים א יח     196 172
306  מלכים א יט     666 556
307  מלכים א כ  494 ?
308  מלכים א כא     392 663
309  מלכים א כב     299 333
310  מלכים ב א  ?   ?
311  מלכים ב ב  239 230
312  מלכים ב ג  244 209
313  מלכים ב ד  265 227
314  מלכים ב ה  431 448
315  מלכים ב ו  529 ?
316  מלכים ב ז  492 ?
317  מלכים ב ח  448 ?
318  מלכים ב ט  826 ?
319  מלכים ב י  632 ?
320  מלכים ב יא     871 ?
321  מלכים ב יב     533 371
322  מלכים ב יג     412 ?
323  מלכים ב יד     810 341
324  מלכים ב טו     767 622
325  מלכים ב טז     ?   656
326  מלכים ב יז     355 ?
327  מלכים ב יח     315 574
328  מלכים ב יט     362 677
329  מלכים ב כ  361 298
330  מלכים ב כא     477 ?
331  מלכים ב כב     556 666
332  מלכים ב כג     414 ?
333  מלכים ב כד     644 369
334  מלכים ב כה     629 510
335  ישעיהו א   78  80
336  ישעיהו ב   289 347
337  ישעיהו ג   99  136
338  ישעיהו ד   526 633
339  ישעיהו ה   148 268
340  ישעיהו ו   241 286
341  ישעיהו ז   485 703
342  ישעיהו ח   261 ?
343  ישעיהו ט   343 717
344  ישעיהו י   226 407
345  ישעיהו יא  585 287
346  ישעיהו יב  687 280
347  ישעיהו יג  715 310
348  ישעיהו יד  151 664
349  ישעיהו טו  ?   ?
350  ישעיהו טז  830 ?
351  ישעיהו יז  872 441
352  ישעיהו יח  874 ?
353  ישעיהו יט  409 472
354  ישעיהו כ   673 ?
355  ישעיהו כא  628 379
356  ישעיהו כב  353 358
357  ישעיהו כג  615 461
358  ישעיהו כד  234 728
359  ישעיהו כה  680 484
360  ישעיהו כו  155 68
361  ישעיהו כז  180 381
362  ישעיהו כח  278 221
363  ישעיהו כט  518 541
364  ישעיהו ל   91  74
365  ישעיהו לא  779 377
366  ישעיהו לב  366 ?
367  ישעיהו לג  124 363
368  ישעיהו לד  751 610
369  ישעיהו לה  508 620
370  ישעיהו לו  802 587
371  ישעיהו לז  768 ?
372  ישעיהו לח  397 705
373  ישעיהו לט  829 ?
374  ישעיהו מ   273 156
375  ישעיהו מא  258 690
376  ישעיהו מב  336 444
377  ישעיהו מג  170 161
378  ישעיהו מד  700 294
379  ישעיהו מה  221 240
380  ישעיהו מו  440 252
381  ישעיהו מז  721 426
382  ישעיהו מח  242 308
383  ישעיהו מט  245 309
384  ישעיהו נ   593 600
385  ישעיהו נא  339 170
386  ישעיהו נב  452 553
387  ישעיהו נג  495 617
388  ישעיהו נד  219 436
389  ישעיהו נה  238 418
390  ישעיהו נו  357 547
391  ישעיהו נז  129 616
392  ישעיהו נח  105 108
393  ישעיהו נט  372 ?
394  ישעיהו ס   300 497
395  ישעיהו סא  369 443
396  ישעיהו סב  543 589
397  ישעיהו סג  405 721
398  ישעיהו סד  334 ?
399  ישעיהו סה  417 384
400  ישעיהו סו  150 300
401  ירמיהו א   624 651
402  ירמיהו ב   171 83
403  ירמיהו ג   164 123
404  ירמיהו ד   307 414
405  ירמיהו ה   345 645
406  ירמיהו ו   403 468
407  ירמיהו ז   367 410
408  ירמיהו ח   527 ?
409  ירמיהו ט   230 137
410  ירמיהו י   438 401
411  ירמיהו יא  453 506
412  ירמיהו יב  437 501
413  ירמיהו יג  672 ?
414  ירמיהו יד  747 481
415  ירמיהו טו  643 684
416  ירמיהו טז  636 538
417  ירמיהו יז  383 246
418  ירמיהו יח  547 558
419  ירמיהו יט  847 ?
420  ירמיהו כ   848 446
421  ירמיהו כא  670 ?
422  ירמיהו כב  488 ?
423  ירמיהו כג  179 692
424  ירמיהו כד  843 ?
425  ירמיהו כה  772 554
426  ירמיהו כו  831 ?
427  ירמיהו כז  597 542
428  ירמיהו כח  696 ?
429  ירמיהו כט  428 ?
430  ירמיהו ל   424 249
431  ירמיהו לא  288 303
432  ירמיהו לב  166 134
433  ירמיהו לג  304 491
434  ירמיהו לד  582 ?
435  ירמיהו לה  ?   ?
436  ירמיהו לו  458 389
437  ירמיהו לז  860 ?
438  ירמיהו לח  853 ?
439  ירמיהו לט  811 649
440  ירמיהו מ   737 696
441  ירמיהו מא  748 678
442  ירמיהו מב  822 638
443  ירמיהו מג  877 ?
444  ירמיהו מד  842 ?
445  ירמיהו מה  ?   523
446  ירמיהו מו  742 606
447  ירמיהו מז  832 ?
448  ירמיהו מח  675 ?
449  ירמיהו מט  441 ?
450  ירמיהו נ   604 557
451  ירמיהו נא  577 223
452  ירמיהו נב  510 ?
453  יחזקאל א   220 153
454  יחזקאל ב   790 697
455  יחזקאל ג   744 ?
456  יחזקאל ד   442 ?
457  יחזקאל ה   780 ?
458  יחזקאל ו   ?   582
459  יחזקאל ז   467 647
460  יחזקאל ח   479 545
461  יחזקאל ט   460 478
462  יחזקאל י   620 535
463  יחזקאל יא  621 674
464  יחזקאל יב  856 ?
465  יחזקאל יג  793 447
466  יחזקאל יד  761 ?
467  יחזקאל טו  783 ?
468  יחזקאל טז  222 588
469  יחזקאל יז  378 ?
470  יחזקאל יח  202 540
471  יחזקאל יט  858 ?
472  יחזקאל כ   502 198
473  יחזקאל כא  267 532
474  יחזקאל כב  786 ?
475  יחזקאל כג  290 529
476  יחזקאל כד  157 257
477  יחזקאל כה  863 ?
478  יחזקאל כו  730 650
479  יחזקאל כז  635 ?
480  יחזקאל כח  763 ?
481  יחזקאל כט  873 ?
482  יחזקאל ל   ?   609
483  יחזקאל לא  723 ?
484  יחזקאל לב  559 ?
485  יחזקאל לג  574 324
486  יחזקאל לד  753 ?
487  יחזקאל לה  ?   ?
488  יחזקאל לו  291 219
489  יחזקאל לז  520 345
490  יחזקאל לח  667 ?
491  יחזקאל לט  678 187
492  יחזקאל מ   469 467
493  יחזקאל מא  507 ?
494  יחזקאל מב  ?   701
495  יחזקאל מג  465 413
496  יחזקאל מד  95  99
497  יחזקאל מה  236 456
498  יחזקאל מו  606 ?
499  יחזקאל מז  622 201
500  יחזקאל מח  480 712
501  הושע א     521 ?
502  הושע ב     147 654
503  הושע ג     613 405
504  הושע ד     176 150
505  הושע ה     314 415
506  הושע ו     326 419
507  הושע ז     532 640
508  הושע ח     818 245
509  הושע ט     724 511
510  הושע י     481 ?
511  הושע יא    653 ?
512  הושע יב    614 ?
513  הושע יג    548 ?
514  הושע יד    335 ?
515  יואל א     669 328
516  יואל ב     482 97
517  יואל ג     828 ?
518  יואל ד     736 ?
519  עמוס א     859 ?
520  עמוס ב     625 ?
521  עמוס ג     549 ?
522  עמוס ד     201 216
523  עמוס ה     396 512
524  עמוס ו     415 ?
525  עמוס ז     473 ?
526  עמוס ח     309 591
527  עמוס ט     503 514
528  עובדיה א   493 440
529  יונה א     814 433
530  יונה ב     676 427
531  יונה ג     423 499
532  יונה ד     583 ?
533  מיכה א     603 ?
534  מיכה ב     470 536
535  מיכה ג     451 330
536  מיכה ד     598 496
537  מיכה ה     803 422
538  מיכה ו     399 ?
539  מיכה ז     389 154
540  נחום א     374 611
541  נחום ב     866 ?
542  נחום ג     ?   544
543  חבקוק א    654 ?
544  חבקוק ב    347 581
545  חבקוק ג    237 492
546  צפניה א    344 601
547  צפניה ב    483 382
548  צפניה ג    312 ?
549  חגיי א     798 372
550  חגיי ב     322 267
551  זכריה א    572 621
552  זכריה ב    388 642
553  זכריה ג    446 653
554  זכריה ד    817 ?
555  זכריה ה    468 ?
556  זכריה ו    ?   ?
557  זכריה ז    844 ?
558  זכריה ח    380 204
559  זכריה ט    270 270
560  זכריה י    602 643
561  זכריה יא   525 248
562  זכריה יב   627 495
563  זכריה יג   683 464
564  זכריה יד   472 179
565  מלאכי א    393 704
566  מלאכי ב    248 194
567  מלאכי ג    97  111
568  דברי הימים א א     719 ?
569  דברי הימים א ב     256 361
570  דברי הימים א ג     704 368
571  דברי הימים א ד     426 583
572  דברי הימים א ה     497 ?
573  דברי הימים א ו     ?   ?
574  דברי הימים א ז     562 714
575  דברי הימים א ח     671 508
576  דברי הימים א ט     795 264
577  דברי הימים א י     ?   ?
578  דברי הימים א יא    762 ?
579  דברי הימים א יב    449 599
580  דברי הימים א יג    816 ?
581  דברי הימים א יד    881 ?
582  דברי הימים א טו    749 ?
583  דברי הימים א טז    728 ?
584  דברי הימים א יז    652 469
585  דברי הימים א יח    869 ?
586  דברי הימים א יט    ?   ?
587  דברי הימים א כ     ?   ?
588  דברי הימים א כא    726 ?
589  דברי הימים א כב    884 283
590  דברי הימים א כג    496 635
591  דברי הימים א כד    805 646
592  דברי הימים א כה    888 ?
593  דברי הימים א כו    509 312
594  דברי הימים א כז    707 688
595  דברי הימים א כח    421 658
596  דברי הימים א כט    454 262
597  דברי הימים ב א     846 577
598  דברי הימים ב ב     812 713
599  דברי הימים ב ג     681 228
600  דברי הימים ב ד     466 118
601  דברי הימים ב ה     688 ?
602  דברי הימים ב ו     662 ?
603  דברי הימים ב ז     809 476
604  דברי הימים ב ח     ?   ?
605  דברי הימים ב ט     825 ?
606  דברי הימים ב י     ?   ?
607  דברי הימים ב יא    ?   ?
608  דברי הימים ב יב    ?   500
609  דברי הימים ב יג    887 370
610  דברי הימים ב יד    806 ?
611  דברי הימים ב טו    834 ?
612  דברי הימים ב טז    820 ?
613  דברי הימים ב יז    ?   ?
614  דברי הימים ב יח    827 428
615  דברי הימים ב יט    813 ?
616  דברי הימים ב כ     567 ?
617  דברי הימים ב כא    637 707
618  דברי הימים ב כב    875 417
619  דברי הימים ב כג    882 ?
620  דברי הימים ב כד    854 199
621  דברי הימים ב כה    876 ?
622  דברי הימים ב כו    759 527
623  דברי הימים ב כז    838 ?
624  דברי הימים ב כח    692 726
625  דברי הימים ב כט    563 259
626  דברי הימים ב ל     824 263
627  דברי הימים ב לא    757 338
628  דברי הימים ב לב    645 ?
629  דברי הימים ב לג    433 ?
630  דברי הימים ב לד    ?   ?
631  דברי הימים ב לה    391 144
632  דברי הימים ב לו    384 619
633  תהילים א   286 398
634  תהילים ב   358 296
635  תהילים ג   436 334
636  תהילים ד   711 400
637  תהילים ה   434 627
638  תהילים ו   878 ?
639  תהילים ז   713 729
640  תהילים ח   515 ?
641  תהילים ט   699 374
642  תהילים י   305 305
643  תהילים יא  766 260
644  תהילים יב  398 242
645  תהילים יג  ?   565
646  תהילים יד  717 ?
647  תהילים טו  638 ?
648  תהילים טז  385 162
649  תהילים יז  651 494
650  תהילים יח  471 406
651  תהילים יט  395 158
652  תהילים כ   840 278
653  תהילים כא  791 ?
654  תהילים כב  390 225
655  תהילים כג  731 449
656  תהילים כד  204 235
657  תהילים כה  490 730
658  תהילים כו  720 ?
659  תהילים כז  710 ?
660  תהילים כח  ?   ?
661  תהילים כט  195 107
662  תהילים ל   544 420
663  תהילים לא  591 390
664  תהילים לב  714 293
665  תהילים לג  320 301
666  תהילים לד  327 318
667  תהילים לה  596 411
668  תהילים לו  406 503
669  תהילים לז  199 516
670  תהילים לח  693 ?
671  תהילים לט  592 460
672  תהילים מ   610 628
673  תהילים מא  457 442
674  תהילים מב  690 434
675  תהילים מג  ?   ?
676  תהילים מד  698 452
677  תהילים מה  175 182
678  תהילים מו  774 ?
679  תהילים מז  513 231
680  תהילים מח  677 175
681  תהילים מט  379 596
682  תהילים נ   163 125
683  תהילים נא  192 613
684  תהילים נב  647 ?
685  תהילים נג  ?   ?
686  תהילים נד  861 567
687  תהילים נה  285 292
688  תהילים נו  725 560
689  תהילים נז  650 120
690  תהילים נח  686 479
691  תהילים נט  879 ?
692  תהילים ס   684 507
693  תהילים סא  729 284
694  תהילים סב  735 112
695  תהילים סג  659 304
696  תהילים סד  ?   ?
697  תהילים סה  321 176
698  תהילים סו  541 568
699  תהילים סז  ?   ?
700  תהילים סח  70  59
701  תהילים סט  328 258
702  תהילים ע   ?   ?
703  תהילים עא  504 306
704  תהילים עב  218 210
705  תהילים עג  608 ?
706  תהילים עד  701 ?
707  תהילים עה  852 474
708  תהילים עו  785 691
709  תהילים עז  781 552
710  תהילים עח  259 189
711  תהילים עט  819 ?
712  תהילים פ   523 636
713  תהילים פא  130 375
714  תהילים פב  325 ?
715  תהילים פג  ?   548
716  תהילים פד  402 302
717  תהילים פה  658 243
718  תהילים פו  709 ?
719  תהילים פז  775 ?
720  תהילים פח  668 332
721  תהילים פט  254 192
722  תהילים צ   276 255
723  תהילים צא  251 222
724  תהילים צב  363 502
725  תהילים צג  476 ?
726  תהילים צד  262 652
727  תהילים צה  633 271
728  תהילים צו  ?   672
729  תהילים צז  849 564
730  תהילים צח  739 ?
731  תהילים צט  546 ?
732  תהילים ק   870 ?
733  תהילים קא  316 559
734  תהילים קב  499 128
735  תהילים קג  287 212
736  תהילים קד  122 432
737  תהילים קה  865 537
738  תהילים קו  127 127
739  תהילים קז  337 490
740  תהילים קח  794 683
741  תהילים קט  455 133
742  תהילים קי  732 421
743  תהילים קיא     655 584
744  תהילים קיב     498 314
745  תהילים קיג     323 217
746  תהילים קיד     568 165
747  תהילים קטו     443 218
748  תהילים קטז     136 106
749  תהילים קיז     796 673
750  תהילים קיח     569 166
751  תהילים קיט     86  76
752  תהילים קכ  689 285
753  תהילים קכא     746 339
754  תהילים קכב     456 343
755  תהילים קכג     ?   602
756  תהילים קכד     850 ?
757  תהילים קכה     660 685
758  תהילים קכו     663 404
759  תהילים קכז     519 359
760  תהילים קכח     545 571
761  תהילים קכט     857 335
762  תהילים קל  716 215
763  תהילים קלא     ?   ?
764  תהילים קלב     648 569
765  תהילים קלג     587 ?
766  תהילים קלד     601 396
767  תהילים קלה     550 354
768  תהילים קלו     590 261
769  תהילים קלז     522 475
770  תהילים קלח     758 ?
771  תהילים קלט     252 598
772  תהילים קמ  777 ?
773  תהילים קמא     839 543
774  תהילים קמב     880 555
775  תהילים קמג     ?   ?
776  תהילים קמד     439 355
777  תהילים קמה     301 234
778  תהילים קמו     656 429
779  תהילים קמז     445 669
780  תהילים קמח     564 430
781  תהילים קמט     712 ?
782  תהילים קנ  661 344
783  איוב א     160 71
784  איוב ב     430 515
785  איוב ג     359 675
786  איוב ד     821 ?
787  איוב ה     193 579
788  איוב ו     416 708
789  איוב ז     734 626
790  איוב ח     864 488
791  איוב ט     340 353
792  איוב י     626 ?
793  איוב יא    561 686
794  איוב יב    560 644
795  איוב יג    594 531
796  איוב יד    401 232
797  איוב טו    422 274
798  איוב טז    837 ?
799  איוב יז    ?   453
800  איוב יח    542 ?
801  איוב יט    674 ?
802  איוב כ     427 561
803  איוב כא    586 592
804  איוב כב    408 208
805  איוב כג    ?   ?
806  איוב כד    342 251
807  איוב כה    738 629
808  איוב כו    557 ?
809  איוב כז    566 394
810  איוב כח    232 167
811  איוב כט    489 211
812  איוב ל     752 498
813  איוב לא    584 687
814  איוב לב    792 480
815  איוב לג    609 360
816  איוב לד    823 ?
817  איוב לה    788 695
818  איוב לו    121 239
819  איוב לז    297 56
820  איוב לח    207 110
821  איוב לט    537 682
822  איוב מ     432 594
823  איוב מא    404 ?
824  איוב מב    703 513
825  משלי א     292 323
826  משלי ב     646 412
827  משלי ג     68  23
828  משלי ד     194 317
829  משלי ה     387 164
830  משלי ו     154 437
831  משלי ז     191 256
832  משלי ח     134 157
833  משלי ט     141 391
834  משלי י     152 69
835  משלי יא    117 233
836  משלי יב    243 408
837  משלי יג    333 325
838  משלי יד    149 224
839  משלי טו    223 431
840  משלי טז    283 244
841  משלי יז    215 163
842  משלי יח    216 ?
843  משלי יט    308 ?
844  משלי כ     318 117
845  משלי כא    108 105
846  משלי כב    104 173
847  משלי כג    96  66
848  משלי כד    296 570
849  משלי כה    182 135
850  משלי כו    511 612
851  משלי כז    94  275
852  משלי כח    263 679
853  משלי כט    235 ?
854  משלי ל     158 180
855  משלי לא    246 630
856  רות א  233 521
857  רות ב  313 241
858  רות ג  517 329
859  רות ד  535 522
860  שיר השירים א   272 121
861  שיר השירים ב   249 ?
862  שיר השירים ג   530 655
863  שיר השירים ד   225 169
864  שיר השירים ה   377 483
865  שיר השירים ו   789 409
866  שיר השירים ז   186 159
867  שיר השירים ח   172 ?
868  קוהלת א    139 138
869  קוהלת ב    411 160
870  קוהלת ג    600 403
871  קוהלת ד    501 79
872  קוהלת ה    264 288
873  קוהלת ו    743 ?
874  קוהלת ז    109 51
875  קוהלת ח    360 350
876  קוהלת ט    311 213
877  קוהלת י    126 77
878  קוהלת יא   514 670
879  קוהלת יב   145 289
880  איכה א     88  505
881  איכה ב     351 471
882  איכה ג     138 188
883  איכה ד     373 351
884  איכה ה     694 229
885  אסתר א     631 ?
886  אסתר ב     381 155
887  אסתר ג     799 661
888  אסתר ד     607 562
889  אסתר ה     851 ?
890  אסתר ו     484 397
891  אסתר ז     616 ?
892  אסתר ח     682 276
893  אסתר ט     183 32
894  אסתר י     807 435
895  דנייאל א   575 585
896  דנייאל ב   371 504
897  דנייאל ג   486 238
898  דנייאל ד   161 524
899  דנייאל ה   571 463
900  דנייאל ו   332 291
901  דנייאל ז   282 395
902  דנייאל ח   800 493
903  דנייאל ט   302 237
904  דנייאל י   303 148
905  דנייאל יא  733 331
906  דנייאל יב  475 378
907  עזרא א     579 607
908  עזרא ב     354 709
909  עזרא ג     538 ?
910  עזרא ד     531 365
911  עזרא ה     ?   ?
912  עזרא ו     570 710
913  עזרא ז     474 618
914  עזרא ח     420 307
915  עזרא ט     552 ?
916  עזרא י     580 113
917  נחמיה א    797 373
918  נחמיה ב    618 625
919  נחמיה ג    ?   ?
920  נחמיה ד    649 533
921  נחמיה ה    740 ?
922  נחמיה ו    808 ?
923  נחמיה ז    702 450
924  נחמיה ח    280 109
925  נחמיה ט    266 90
926  נחמיה י    691 337
927  נחמיה יא   855 711
928  נחמיה יב   833 ?
929  נחמיה יג   787 465
```