# What belongs to a married woman and what can she do with it

Tags: halacha, marriage, transactions

Please correct me if I am wrong.

1. Everything a wife brings into her marriage (belonged to her before the marriage), and the Kiddushin object (he gives it to her as a complete present)  belongs to her.
2. That gifts that were given to her after the marriage (only if they were given on the condition that the husband does not have a part in them) belong to her.
3. The money she makes, (if she works more than is required of her, or if she says "I will feed myself and keep what I make").
4. This I am not sure about if she owns what the husband is obligated to give her i.e., a mat, a spoon, pocket money (maybe only if she eats alone).
5. If she inherits something after the marriage.
6. Her kesuba (money); she can sell it as a trust that if her husband dies or divorces her he will need to pay the buyer.
7. From https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/51143/5120 ("Therefore, the man should give the woman a piece of jewelry since he doesn't have rights to her clothing or jewelry") it seems that clothing that she receives belongs to her and it is not under the husband's control.

Are these all the possibilities of a married woman to increase her property?

I heard that everything she owns, the husband manages (and keeps the profits).  (And she will only get it back  (either the same amount or what is was worth when the husband started managing it) after he dies or divorces her.)

How does this work with point 3,4 and 6 (Can she only use it for what the husband allows, or does she keeps it until after the marriage?)

If it works a different way please explain.

Every answer b"n a +1 (even not complete).

Specific sources on the subject will  be really appreciated.

Comment: So you want a summary of Kesuboth Ch. 8 -  http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01141.html#HtmpReportNum0007_L5 or/and Even Ha'Ezer 84-85: http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01974_part_4.html#HtmpReportNum0018_L2

Comment: @DannySchoemann it seems so. thank you these sources are also a answer for me

Comment: @DannySchoemann I just read the shulchan aruch and this is exactly what I was looking for, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The primary source would be the Mishnayot in the [8th chapter of Kesuboth](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01141.html#HtmpReportNum0007_L5) and the related [Gemara](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_00920.html#HtmpReportNum0007_L5).

The Shulchan Aruch codes this in [Even Ha'Ezer 84-85](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01974_part_4.html#HtmpReportNum0018_L2)