# Why don't people ever get married via a shtar kiddushin?

Tags: marriage, legal-documents, kiddushin-eirusin, maseches-kiddushin

The Mishnah on [Kiddushin 2a](https://www.sefaria.org/Kiddushin.2a.1?lang=bi&with=Rashi&lang2=bi) lists 3 ways a woman can be *mekudeshet* (betrothed): via **money**, via the act of **intercourse**, via a ***shtar*** (document).

Now I understand 2 of the acquisition methods:

- ✅ **money**- the method universally used today
- ❌  **intercourse**-  it's licentious, Chazal were against it ([Yevamos 52a](https://www.sefaria.org/Yevamot.52a.6?lang=bi&with=Rashi&lang2=en)) so much so that one would get *makkas mardus* if they attempted to *mekadesh* this way (Rambam [Hilchos Issurei Biah 21:14](https://www.sefaria.org/Yevamot.52a.6?lang=bi&p2=Mishneh_Torah%2C_Forbidden_Intercourse.21.14&lang2=bi&w2=Sheets&lang3=en))

But why don't people ever get married via a ***shtar*** kiddushin?

Comment: Very related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/51141/ring-and-kiddushin

Comment: I think most of the Halachic opinions treat the Kesubah as such a Shtar "supporting" the ring. Also one Kiddushin is enough and your question might ask "why the ring is preferable over the Shtar"?

Comment: To add to DoubleAA’s point, it’s not just that one has a shtar written up - already complicated enough - but that, unlike by a ring, the document must be written with her knowledge and can lead to cases of doubtful Kiddushin otherwise (SA EH 32:1). Perhaps this is why it’s done with a ring - less complicated, and less chances of a doubtful Kiddushin (still possible, but less likely).

Comment: It might be helpful to distinguish between kesef - i.e. legal tender - and shaveh kesef - i.e. a ring - for your discussion

Comment: https://www.yutorah.org/sidebar/lecture.cfm/915325/rabbi-elihu-abbe/kiddushei-shtar/

Comment: @רבותמחשבות gevaldik! I actually grew up with R' Elihu and went to MDS with him up until 3rd grade! #smallworld

Comment: @AlBerko "Kesubah viewed as as Shtar "supporting" the ring???  Most of the Halachic opinions??? Can you name at least one?

Comment: @IsraelReader Names is not my cup of tea. But  I consulted a knowledgable Rabbi here in Jerusalem regarding a secular couple that don't want to use the standard procedure and only want a fancy ketubah that says the he takes her בברית נשואין. And the Rabbi said it works as a Shtar.

Comment: @AlBerko I might even agree with that rabbi in the case that you mentioned. However you're moving the goalposts with that case. Until now, we were speaking a standard Kesubah, which you claim is a Shtar "supporting" the ring. What does that even mean? You make a fantastic claim that this is "most of the Halachic opinions", without being able to cite even one. What is your credibility?

Comment: @IsraelReader If the Kesubah was given silently without anything else before two witnesses would it be considered Kiddushin in your opinion?

Comment: @AlBerko An act of Kiddushin, needs אמירה, a declaration of intent. However עסוקים באותו ענין, if the parties were involved in the discussion of marriage, suffices as the אמירה. Hence in the case of the non-standard ketubah that, says the he takes her בברית נשואין, and which he hands to her in the context of a marriage "ceremony", that *might* count as אמירה. We would need to examine validity of that wording of the ketubah, especially in light of the opinion quoted in the Rema (EH 27:3) אמר לה הרי את נשואתי י״א שאינו כלום.

Comment: An interesting Psak of Rav Hayi Gaon quoted in [Kovets Shitot Kamae Yevamot 90b](https://beta.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=47914&st=&pgnum=494&hilite=) to make Kiddushin with Shtar Irusin only.

Answer (score 5):

The Rambam writes how the Minhag of Klal Yisrael is to use Kesef or Shaveh Kesef, not Shtar; although, shetar is also an option. Rav Hershel Schachter ([Kiddushin 5777 - Pesichah](https://www.yutorah.org/sidebar/lecture.cfm/862011/rabbi-hershel-schachter/pesichah-to-maseches-kiddushin-5776/)) quotes Prof. Simcha Assaf (from a book he found in his father's library) who thinks this is one of the Rambam's attacks on the Karaites, emphasizing how we believe in Torah Shebaal Peh. Kesef is learned from Torah Shebaal Peh (Kichah Kichah), and Shaveh Kesef is another Derasha on top of that. See also [Kiddushin 5777 #21](https://www.yutorah.org/sidebar/lecture.cfm/865167/rabbi-hershel-schachter/kiddushin-21-chazarah-1/) and [Bava Kamma 5779 #16](https://www.yutorah.org/sidebar/lecture.cfm/908748/rabbi-hershel-schachter/bava-kamma-16-8a-sheibuda-deoraisa-milveh-beshtar-vs-beal-peh-the-rambam-and-karaim/).

This is rooted in the Rambam's view of Kiddushei Kesef as the only one of the three that is Divrei Sofrim, meaning Torah Shebaal Peh.

**משנה תורה הלכות אישות ג:כא**

> אע"פ שעיקר הדברים כן הוא נהגו כל ישראל לקדש בכסף או בשוה כסף, וכן אם רצה לקדש בשטר מקדש, אבל אין מקדשין בביאה לכתחלה ואם קידש בביאה מכין אותו מכת מרדות כדי שלא יהיו ישראל פרוצים נ בדבר זה אע"פ שקידושיו קידושין גמורין.

Other relevant Rambams include Hilchot Shabbat (2:1, 7:1), Milah (2:1), and Shechitah (12:10).

Comment: Mekach u’memchar exists elsewhere as well. To me the point seems to be that it’s as many derashos as possible (two by Shava Kesef vs. one by shtar); the Karaites would seemingly *only* hold of Kidushei Bi’ah, which is explicit in the passuk.

Comment: Money exists also in mekach umemkar

Comment: Since you're quoting Rav Herschel Schachter, I heard him in a shiur say the Rambam in a yeshiva says himself what you quote from a historian. Don't know where

Comment: I think he quotes it from Prof. Simcha Assaf, but I need to clarify

Comment: ***In a teshuva, not yeshiva

Comment: Maybe you're remembering the debate about Tevilah, which I forgot to add.
http://www.daat.ac.il/encyclopedia/value.asp?id1=2319#koteret2

Comment: I edited my answer after clarifying the details of what he said

Answer (score 3):

At the simplest level -- and I have heard MDjava's answer as well, to show we value the Oral Law -- kessef is more foolproof than a Shtar. A Gett, for instance, requires people with lots of training and specialization, and painstaking attention to detail about how names and locations are spelled. A Shtar Kiddushin would require something similar to a Gett.