# Origin of wedding rings

Tags: halacha, marriage, wedding

Where did the custom of giving wedding rings originate?

Was it always a part of Jewish custom, or was it adopted by other cultures, and if so, how come it is so important that we have Halachas surrounding it?

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/51141/ring-and-kiddushin

Comment: Not sure why this closed? The above that @Chatzkel shared doesn’t delve into the origins specifically regarding the tradition, but rather the reason for it under the chuppah. It is seemingly a custom adopted by many cultures, and the question is if we took it from other cultures, or if we have a specific origin / proof for it?