# Meaning / Significance of the Ring on planet Saturn

Tags: midrash, astronomy

Shabbos and the planet Saturn are linked. I was wondering if anyone has a source for the ring(s) on the planet Saturn being a wedding between the Jews / Shabbos / Hashem? I heard this idea before but cannot find an authentic source.

Comment: The ring on Saturn was not known until relatively recently. And a wedding does not require a ring.

Comment: I can't yet find an answer to my question but I can confidently conclude this idea is not from chazal and must be from kabbala. And to make matters worse, as you wrote, the rings were discovered in 1610 or 1655 (see discussion in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rings_of_Saturn) which means that we have to bring up many questions about ruach hakodesh if it ultimately comes from an earlier source.

Comment: If it comes from a later source, then it has to come from a source that is post-Ari, i.e. 1700's or 1800's chassidus.

Comment: But to address your "wedding doesn't require a ring", the ring is the accepted minhag with many deep reasons some of which are kabbalistic (see e.g. https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/51141/ring-and-kiddushin). So I imagine if I ultimately find a source about Saturn's rings, it would shtim nicely with the wedding idea. 

More to come later when I have time.

Comment: Shabbos = Saturn = Malchus. I heard from a Kabbalist that Malchus has 7 makifim. There are 7 main rings of Saturn as written about on NASA's site [here](https://science.nasa.gov/resource/saturns-rings-2/). I'm still searching for a source as I didn't have much time to discuss it at length.

Comment: Thus, it seems my prompt about the connection of Saturn to the "wedding" between Shabbos and Jews is not supported (thus far).